# Display a nested session variable in PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to echo product_name with

```
echo $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]["product_name"];
```

but that's not working.

This is var_dump($_SESSION)

```
array(4) {
  ["shopping_cart"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["product_id"]=>
      string(2) "99"
      ["product_name"]=>
      string(32) "Booster Juice Concentrate"
    }
  }
```

How can I echo "product_name"?

TIA

Comment: `$_SESSION['shopping_cart][0]['product_name']`, or `$cart = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]; $product_name = current($cart)["product_name"];`, or iterate over the cart `foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $products) { echo $products['product_name']; }`. But if you have more than 1 item in the cart, then either the first option with a different index (i.e. `[1]`, `[2]`) or iterating over the cart items is how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your session have shopping_cart and shopping_cart is a array, so the right one is

```php
echo $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0]["product_name"];
```

because you wanna get the name of first product, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your array of shopping cart is an array that contains an array of different items in it.  Then each item in that array is an array itself.
To echo out the first product name you would write:

```
echo $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0]["product_name"];
```

Eventually, you will need to go over each of these elements in a for loop when you have more than one product in the cart

```
foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product){
  echo $product['product_name'] . "<br>";
}
```